# Can't get the NumberPickers from TimePicker - Android version 7.0 (API 24)

Tags: xamarin.android, sdk, timepicker, android-number-picker

I have an Android.Widget.NumberPicker in my app and I'm using a FindAllChildernByType method to get the NumberPickers inside.
It seems that the NumberPicker is different on Android version 7.0 (API 24). There is no NumberPickers, only TexViews, so when running on this OS, the app crashes.

Is it a known issue? Thus anyone came up with a nice solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace for the crash as it should be working fine!

Comment: My FindAllChildernByType<NumberPickers> method returns an empty list - only in API 24. The exception is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" because I'm expecting a list of 3 values...

Comment: Please post some code here, and let us to try to reproduce your issue.